# Need split the data when condition is getting changed without loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Below is my table

```
if exists(select top 1 1 from sys.tables where name='ObjInfo')
drop table ObjInfo

  create table ObjInfo(id int identity
                     ,ObjNumber int
,ObjDate datetime
,ObjConditionId int)
 
  insert into ObjInfo(ObjNumber,ObjDate,ObjConditionId)
  values(1,'2014-01-03',1)
  ,(1,'2014-01-05',1)
  ,(1,'2014-01-06',1)
  ,(1,'2014-01-08',2)
  ,(1,'2014-01-13',1)
  ,(1,'2014-01-15',1)
  ,(1,'2014-01-25',4)
  ,(2,'2014-01-01',1)
  ,(2,'2014-01-05',1)
  ,(2,'2014-01-07',2)
  ,(2,'2014-01-08',2)
  ,(2,'2014-01-12',2)
  ,(2,'2014-01-14',3)
  ,(2,'2014-01-15',4)
```

My Job is to display ObjectNumbers wise  when condition was changed and for which time period.
My expected output is as below

```
ObjNumber ObjConditionId ConditionBeg ConditionEnd
1           1           2014-01-03      2014-01-08
1           2           2014-01-08      2014-01-13
1           1           2014-01-13      2014-01-25
1           4           2014-01-25      getdate()
2           1           2014-01-01      2014-01-07
2           2           2014-01-07      2014-01-14
2           3           2014-01-14      2014-01-15
2           4           2014-01-15      getdate()
```

I am trying below code but not getting how can I achieve this.

```
WITH ConditionCTE AS (
  SELECT ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, ObjDate AS ConditionBeg,
         LEAD(ObjDate, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjNumber ORDER BY ObjDate) AS ConditionEnd
  FROM ObjInfo
)
SELECT ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, ConditionBeg,
       CASE WHEN CAST(ConditionEnd as date)= GETDATE() THEN 'getdate()' ELSE ConditionEnd END AS ConditionEnd
FROM ConditionCTE
ORDER BY ObjNumber, ConditionBeg;
```

Comment: Do note that `GETDATE()` returns current date and time. So the condition in your case expression only evaluates to true on midnight `00:00:00`

Comment: It looks like you have a *gaps-and-islands* type of dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic gaps-and-island problem; you can use the difference between row numbers to identify groups.

This gives you for each island, with its start and end dates:

```
select ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, 
    min(ObjDate) MinObjDate, 
    max(ObjDate) MaxObjDate
from (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by ObjNumber                 order by ObjDate) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by ObjNumber, ObjConditionId order by ObjDate) rn2
    from ObjInfo o
) o
group by ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, rn1 - rn2
order by ObjNumber, MinObjDate
```

If you want to the start of the next island as `MaxObjDate` instead, as shown in your expected results, we can use `lead()` on top of this (the three-arguments form allows us to provide a default value):

```
select ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, 
    min(ObjDate) MinObjDate, 
    lead(min(ObjDate), 1, getdate()) over(partition by ObjNumber order by min(ObjDate)) MaxObjDate
from (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by ObjNumber                 order by ObjDate) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by ObjNumber, ObjConditionId order by ObjDate) rn2
    from ObjInfo o
) o
group by ObjNumber, ObjConditionId, rn1 - rn2
order by ObjNumber, MinObjDate
```

**[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sYBRLGGG)**

| ObjNumber | ObjConditionId | MinObjDate | MaxObjDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2 | 2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 1 | 2014-01-13 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 4 | 2014-01-25 00:00:00.000 | 2023-06-06 08:46:17.283 |
| 2 | 1 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 3 | 2014-01-14 00:00:00.000 | 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 4 | 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-06-06 08:46:17.283 |

Comment: Thank you GMB for the optimized solution